# Why are there some packages in the Software application but not in apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, gnome-software

I recently moved from Debian to Ubuntu, I usually used `apt` to install package (and don't want to use the software center as apt it let me know which package are installed as dependencies).

But I already found something I wasn't expecting:
some package like `atom` and `discord` are available in the software center but not in apt, isn't the software center a graphic interface for `apt`? does it use something else?

Comment: You didn't say which version you are running, but the later versions use the 'software' found upstream (eg. gnome's, kde's if you are using kubuntu etc).  `aptitude` or `synaptic` maybe more familiar to you.

Comment: @guiverc I'm running the software center v3.28.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have just discovered "snap" packages, they are deployed by "snappy" package management system built by Canonical Ltd. (the Ubuntu company).

> Snaps are containerised software packages that are simple to create and install. They auto-update and are safe to run.

Read more here: https://docs.snapcraft.io/getting-started/3876

The *Software* application also contains snaps, in fact

> Some applications are available in both formats. In such a case in Ubuntu Software the snap will be listed first. ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-remove.html.en))

Comment: You could also mention that snaps are (generally) listed above the deb version in the Software Center.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1075319/248158 which links to https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-remove.html.en which has "Applications are available in two formats: snap packages and Debian packages. An application available as a snap package is from now on referred to as a snap. **Some applications are available in both formats. In such a case in Ubuntu Software the snap will be listed first**."

Comment: When a package is available on both would you advise me to use snap or apt ?

Comment: @jonatjano There is [one Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029610/if-a-package-is-available-as-both-a-deb-and-a-snap-which-method-is-preferrable) about this, but I suspect the answers are subjective. Other relevant questions and answers: https://askubuntu.com/q/948861, https://askubuntu.com/q/761245, https://askubuntu.com/q/866511, https://askubuntu.com/q/618471, https://askubuntu.com/a/1079209 (read the comments below this answer too)

Answer (score 7):

> isn't the software center a graphic interface for apt

No. Ubuntu software center also supports `snap` installation. See the [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/store) store.  Discord on command line would be

```
sudo snap install discord
```

and atom would be

```
sudo snap install --classic atom
```

Comment: Atom (and Discord) can be installed without snap, you can use a PPA for Atom and download Discord's self-updating .deb

Comment: @cat sure but he was asking about default Ubuntu. So that is regular apt and snaps. Not 3rd party. I would even advice against 3rd party if there is a snap.

Comment: yes, except that snaps are not nearly as reliable or usable out-of-the-box as installed packages with `dpkg` and it's understandable if some user should wonder whether the snap command is unnecessary. +1 regardless